# cannot convert string to int after receiving data in java

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

i have arduino that send 2 int and the int was separate by " : "
for example my arduino send data = 12315: 15123

after i send that data using bluetooth, i receive the data in smartphone and i need that 2 value that i receive become int again 
this is was my part code on my android

```
 void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {

                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {

                                            String[] tmp;
                                            String lol,dam;
                                            tmp = data.split(":");
                                            try
                                            {


                                                lol = String.valueOf(crypt[0])+":"+String.valueOf(crypt[1]);
                                                derajat.setText(lol);
                                            }
                                            catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
                                            {
                                                // bad data - set to sentinel
                                                crypt[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                                                crypt[1] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                                                derajat.setText("none");
                                            }

                                            dam = tmp[0]+":"+tmp[1];

                                            myLabel.setText(dam);
                                              //derajat.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }
```

as you can see that after '\n' data will be process
first i split using data.split() and i get 2 value that stored in tmp
after that i parse that value to crypt[0] and crypt[1]
i set text to derajat to see my value

and i set text the result in myLabel too
i can see my value in myLabel but i cant convert it to int because i see nothing in label derajat
can somebody help me why i cant convert int after receiving that data ??

Comment: Where is `crypt` defined? Shouldn't you be using `temp` there as well?

Comment: i use  int[] crypt=new int[10], i use it in global bcause i need to use that value in other class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the received data from your Arduino is in fact as you have specified:

```
"12315: 15123"
```

Then what is happening is that you are getting a **NumberFormatException** which you do ***catch*** but really have no way of knowing other than **derajat** will contain nothing (or "none")....which is exactly what you are experiencing.

The reason you would get a **NumberFormatException** is because there is a white-space directly after the colon (:) delimiter so when you try to carry out:

```
crypt[1] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
```

(tmp[1] actually holds " 15123") a **NumberFormatException** is thrown. The **Integer.parseInt()** method will not handle white-spaces within the numerical string. To remedy this trim your split strings, for example:

```
crypt[0] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0].trim());
crypt[1] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim());
```

or split with:

```
tmp = data.split(": ");
```